# How can I support different resolutions with Monogame?

Tags: xna, c#, monogame

I want to support the following 4 resolutions in my Windows Phone 8 game: 480 × 800, 768 × 1280, 720 × 1280, 1080 x 1920.
How can I do that with Monogame? If I draw a sprite with Monogame, the sprite is not drawn on the right place in every resolution. For example, with a resolution of 768 × 1280, the sprite is drawn in the center of the screen, but if I use another resolution, the sprite is no more drawn in the center of the screen.

What should I do so that the sprite is in every resolution on the same place?

Comment: try something like this http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/Series2D/Resolution_independency.php

Answer (score -1):

You must resize all your image, and use some maths for positions.

I don't know XNA, but I will give you a code that you will adapt with this lib.

**Images**

**1.** You will do everything based on 1 screen resolution, and scale your images, relative to this.

```
float Reference_Screen_X = 1280;
float Reference_Screen_Y = 720;
```

**2.** You will get your current screen resolution

```
float Screen_X = GetScreenWidth(); //your function to get the screen width
float Screen_Y = GetScreenHeight();
```

**3.** You will resize all your image this way

```
float size_x = image.getwidth() * ( Screen_X / Reference_Screen_X );
float size_y = image.getheight() * ( Screen_Y / Reference_Screen_Y );
image.setSize(size_x, size_y);
```

**OR** with scale methods

```
float scale_x = 1 * ( Screen_X / Reference_Screen_X );
float scale_y = 1 * ( Screen_Y / Reference_Screen_Y );
image.setScale(scale, scale);
```

**Positions**

**4.** You have to keep in mind that every value you will set, will be in a Reference_Screen coordinate.

For exemple if you want go to the middle of the screen :

```
image.x = 640 * ( Screen_X / Reference_Screen_X );
```

**Shortcuts**

You should use global variables like :

```
  float refToScreen_x = ( Screen_X / Reference_Screen_X );
  float refToScreen_y = ( Screen_Y / Reference_Screen_Y );
```

Then you just multiply them to the number you want :

```
 x = 500 * refToScreen_x;
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: This is a very complicated way of doing it.

Comment: @craftworkgames, this way is very simple, I just add the image scaling for him. If you have a simplier way, I would be glad to see it

Comment: Will my sprites always have the same proportions if I change the resolution? For example, I don't want that a circle looks oval on a different resolution. Which code should I use so that my circles don't look oval?

Comment: @LeSam I can't post an answer here because the question has been closed. I've put a quick tutorial on my blog. Oh and sorry about the downvote, your answer does work after all but recommending people use global variables in calculations every time a coordinate is set is a bad practice that leads to buggy hard to maintain code. http://www.craftworkgames.com/blog/monogame-resolution-independence/

Comment: @Homer_Simpson you should ask another question

Comment: As @craftworkgames mentioned, it's really complicated to have to resize each and every game object separately, as you seem to be advocating. The math is indeed simple, but what's not simple is having to do this over and over again for each (x,y) coordinate, as well as object dimensions - especially since `SpriteBatch.Begin` has a [handy overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff433701.aspx) which will do all the transformations for you.